# OPENCV 4.04 > THRESH_OTSU mode: > 'src_type == CV_8UC1 || src_type == CV_16UC1' > where > 'src_type' is 6 (CV_64FC1)

Tags: python, opencv

Im getting this mistake in pyhton, opencv
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/prosses/main.py", line 116, in 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-hfoi92lm\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1557: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'double __cdecl cv::threshold(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,double,double,int)'

> THRESH_OTSU mode:
> 'src_type == CV_8UC1 || src_type == CV_16UC1'
> where
> 'src_type' is 6 (CV_64FC1)

[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-hfoi92lm\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

Comment: What code are you to running, and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. It's hard to guess what you're doing and what you expected to happen from your question. Also, search for any unexpected error online to form an idea what might cause it and replace the title of your question with a real title, not a bunch of code missing any context!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  People here are very helpful if given a clear question formatted so they can read it.  They cannot help with an error message out of context. Please use the markdown formatting to show your code as code and to show the error messages as unformatted text.  Then ask a specific question about it.

Comment: As the error says, `THRESH_OTSU` can only be used on images with type `CV_8UC1` or `CV_16UC1`. Apparently, you are passing a floating-point image.

Answer (score 9):

Pay attention to the image data type, the type must be 'uint8' because the algorithm calculates the gray level, but gray level needs to be ensured 'uint8'.

```
image = image.astype("uint8")
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV Error: You cant pass multiple streams into the function you're using. Do this instead

```
a, b, c = cv2.split(image)
```

now pass either a or b or c into the function as a single image stream